# SwiftUI - Graphically reduce a VStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to graphically reduce a View or a `VStack` like I saw in a video. The guy selects the `VStack` and by pressing on his keyboard he gets a thumbnail of his `VStack`.
I have this :

```
VStack {
    TextField("Placeholder", text: $newValue)
        .background(Color.white)
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text("Button")
    }
}.padding()
```

and I'd like to have to this:

```
VStack{...}.padding()
```

What are the keyboard keys to enter?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video and the timestamp showing the behaviour you saw, so that we know what you are talking about?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285997/xcode-swift-code-folding-collapse) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode Swift code folding/collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285997/xcode-swift-code-folding-collapse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Code Folding. Can be done by pressing the following keys together.

`Opt + Cmd + Left Arrow Key` (⌥ + ⌘ + ⇠) after the opening brace of your VStack

More shortcuts here: https://swifteducation.github.io/assets/pdfs/XcodeKeyboardShortcuts.pdf

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is called "Code Folding" and can be accessed in multiple ways:

- (Menu) Editor > Code Folding > Fold
  [image]
- By clicking the left ribbon of the scope you want to fold
  [image]
- By using the shortcut `⌥ ⌘ ←` (or the variant most suitable for the case)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt + Cmd + ← (arrow left)| collapse method

Ctrl + Alt + Cmd + → (arrow right) | expand metnod